# Is there any way to be healed by energy (fire) damage?

Tags: dnd-5e

Pretty much what the title says. Is there any published content (or combination thereof), whether a class feature, spell, feat, racial trait, magic item or whatever that would let a character by healed instead when taking elemental damage? I'm mostly interested in Fire damage, but if it's only possible with some other element that's also fine.

This needs to be for a player character. I know there's some monsters that can do it, but they're not playable.

Comment: What do you mean by "to be healed"? To regain hit points quickly?

Comment: @enkryptor ideally, yes, regaining hp instead of taking the damage.

Comment: This is basically how I played late-game FF6 - all characters taking 9999 heal each turn from merton. :-)

Comment: Do you mean to exclude player options like Wild Shape and Polymorph that give access to the monsters with these traits indirectly? Claiming that monsters aren't playable isn't always accurate.

Comment: @JoelHarmon hm, I suppose those might also be interesting (although I think only True Polymorph would work since the others are limited to Beasts?)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### The Dragon Masks from the Rise of Tiamat Supplement

The [Rise of Tiamat Supplement](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/RiseTiamatSupplementv0.2_Printer.pdf) contains notes on several legendary magic Dragon Masks, one for each color of chromatic dragon. All masks share the same relevant property:

> **Damage Absorption.** You have resistance against
> the mask’s damage type. If you already have resistance
> to that damage type from another source, you instead
> have immunity to that damage type. If you already have
> immunity to that damage type from another source,
> whenever you are subjected to damage of that type, you
> take none of that damage and regain a number of hit
> points equal to half the damage dealt of that type.

If you somehow gain immunity to fire damage and attune to the Red Dragon mask (which is associated with fire), you will take no fire damage and instead be healed for half of the fire damage that would have been dealt.

Comment: To add to this, I played with someone who used exactly that (though I don't recall what he used to gain immunity in the first place) at Gencon a couple weeks ago.

Comment: With this and the level 0 Fire Bolt, can I heal myslef at will?

Comment: Sounds like you can heal at-will with it, which makes the item really broken.

Comment: @Cyrad Once you have given a character an artefact, all bets are off.

Comment: @Mindwin Ah, that explains it.

Comment: plus, immunity itself is very powerful, @Cyrad

Answer (score 10):

The Dragon Masks from the Rise of Tiamat

> Damage Absorption. You have resistance against the mask’s damage type.
>   If you already have resistance to that damage type from another
>   source, you instead have immunity to that damage type. If you already
>   have immunity to that damage type from another source, whenever you
>   are subjected to damage of that type, you take none of that damage and
>   regain a number of hit points equal to half the damage dealt of that
>   type.

These combined with certain spells, items, race and/or class features;

- Spell Investiture of Fire + Red Mask
- Spell Investiture of Ice + White Mask
- Ring of Fire Elemental Command + Red Mask
- Ring of Earth Elemental Command + Black Mask
- Ring of Air Elemental Command + Blue Mask
- Moon Druid's Elemental Wild Shape(lv 10) air, water or earth + Green Mask, fire + Red or Green Masks (might need DM permission to wear the mask)
- Sorcerer's Favored Soul, Divine Purity(lv 14) + Green Mask
- Sorcerer's Storm Soul, Wind Soul(lv 18) + Blue Mask
- Monk's Purity of Body(lv 10) + Green Mask

Comment: This is just all that I can think of off the top of my head, will need do some research to be able to come up with anymore.