# Is healing by fire possible?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, healing, damage-types

I know this exact question was asked for 5e but I play 3.5 which has more options so I'm wondering if there's a way for a player character to heal from fire, similar to an Iron Golem. It doesn't matter if it's a spell, template, magic item, etc. Just so long as, instead of taking damage from fire, the character would heal hit points instead.

Is healing by fire possible?

Comment: Related but not a dupe as this question asks about 5e: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106258/is-there-any-way-to-be-healed-by-energy-fire-damage

Comment: Resurrection via fire is also possible.

Comment: Nijineko, how do you resurrect via fire?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all it is worth to mention that an Iron Golem only heals from fire spells, not regular fire. Still it is possible to somehow "heal from fire".

A feat **Healing flames** from Races of Faerun allows a fire genasi or a tanarukk to heal by touching a source of fire, with ammount depending on its size.

A soulmeld **Phoenix belt** from Magic of Incarnum, grants fast healing 1 for 1 round for every point of damage negated by your fire resistance.

Comment: I might have to look into that Pheonix Belt. It sounds perfect

Comment: [This is fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkgiy.jpg)

Comment: FWIW, Pathfinder also has a similar effect. It's called "Fire in the Blood". Found in race builder system. Not very good (capped).

Answer (score 4):

The **iron half-golem template** (*Monster Manual II* p.209 - 212) grants the iron golem's fire healing ability.

However, it has no level adjustment (ECL) listed, and the [*Monster Manual II* D&D 3.5 update document](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/files/DnD35_Monster_Manual_2.zip) does not add a level adjustment, making it difficult to play this as a player character. Since it has magic immunity, it's probably not suited for use as a player character.

The **brass half-golem** (*Monster Manual II* web enhancement) has the same ability.

Comment: Even more important than magic immunity—which honestly causes about as many problems as it solves—is the fact that half-golems tend to go omnicidally insane.

Comment: @KRyan Whoah! Hang on! Since when is a hatred of all flesh creatures considered omnicidal?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Well, “homicidally insane” seemed like a poor argument against PC status. I suppose I should have coined “carnecidal.”